# Modifying existing XValues of Chart in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I try to change existing XValues of a Series object:

```
Set Co = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("META").ChartObjects(1)
Dim RestPos as Long

 Dim oldValues
 oldValues = Co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues
 oldValues(RestPos) = "New Value"

 Co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = oldValues
```

At the last line I got an error "Application-defined or object-defined error"

How to get around this?

Comment: I actually think you need to activate the chart and replace `Co.chart.` with `ActiveChart.`

Comment: Don't think so. I can change the value from "Co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(1).Caption" without any problem. If this was about the chart object this should fail, too

Comment: There should not be any need to select/activate the chart in this case.

Comment: Your code works when I test it.  Can you provide some more detail, screenshot of your data range, etc.?

Comment: See my test:  http://imgur.com/3YawrJp

Comment: The above code works for me too

Comment: Hmm. Thats weird. It does not even work if I do not change "oldvalues" at all. But there does not seem to be any other magic in that code, too

Comment: ONE thing might be different. It is on ANOTHER Chart. Updated the question

Comment: Another Chart? O_O. I don't see any updates in your question...

Comment: Just the first Line clearifying, that "co" is from another Worksheet. I meant another Sheet, not Chart of course :)